# ¿Como hacer para subir una foto de perfil y una de portada en el mismo codigo y mismo formulario?

Tags: php8

Hola que tal estoy creando un sistema donde los usuarios puedan elegir su foto de perfil y foto de portada, pero he intentado de todo y solo logro que suba foto de perfil la de portada no, ya intente de todo y no lo logro, este es mi codigo inicial en el cual solo sube foto de perfil.

```
<?php
include_once 'assets/system/core.php';
$foto1   = $_FILES["imagen"]["name"];
$foto    = rand(0,9).rand(100,9999).rand(100,9999).".".$foto1;
$ruta    = $_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"];
$destino = "uploads/profile_fotos/".$foto;

$selecionar = "SELECT foto_perfil FROM usuarios WHERE id = '".$myuser->id."'";
$resultado_seleccionar = mysqli_query($db, $selecionar);

$foto_db = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_seleccionar);
$ruta_foto_db = "uploads/profile_fotos/" . $foto_db['foto_perfil'];

if(file_exists($ruta_foto_db)){
unlink($ruta_foto_db);
}

if (!file_exists($destino)) {
move_uploaded_file($ruta,$destino);
}

if($_FILES["imagen"]["name"]){
$editar   = mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE usuarios SET foto_perfil = '$foto' WHERE id = 
'".$myuser->id."' LIMIT 1");
echo "<script> alert ('Foto de perfil actualizada correctamente.'); 
window.location='perfil/".$myuser->id."' </script>";
}
```

y este es mi codigo ya modificado para subir foto de perfil y foto de portada a su vez pero no funciona.

```
<?php
include_once 'assets/system/core.php';

$foto1   = $_FILES["imagen"]["name"];
$foto    = rand(0,9).rand(100,9999).rand(100,9999).".".$foto1;
$ruta    = $_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"];
$destino = "uploads/profile_fotos/".$foto;

$foto2   = $_FILES["imagen2"]["name"];
$foto11    = rand(0,9).rand(100,9999).rand(100,9999).".".$foto2;
$ruta1    = $_FILES["imagen2"]["tmp_name"];
$destino1 = "uploads/cover_fotos/".$foto11;

$selecionar = "SELECT foto_perfil, foto_portada FROM usuarios WHERE id = '".$myuser->id."'";
$resultado_seleccionar = mysqli_query($db, $selecionar);

$foto_db = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_seleccionar);
$ruta_foto_db = "uploads/profile_fotos/" . $foto_db['foto_perfil'];
$ruta_foto_db1 = "uploads/cover_fotos/" . $foto_db['foto_portada'];

if(file_exists($ruta_foto_db) && file_exists($ruta_foto_db1)){
    unlink($ruta_foto_db);
    unlink($ruta_foto_db1);
}

if (!file_exists($destino) && !file_exists($destino1)) {
    move_uploaded_file($ruta,$destino);
    move_uploaded_file($ruta1,$destino1);
}

if($_FILES["imagen"]["name"]){
    $editar   = mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE usuarios SET foto_perfil = '$foto' WHERE id = '".$myuser->id."' LIMIT 1");
    echo "<script> alert ('Foto de perfil actualizada correctamente.'); window.location='perfil/".$myuser->id."' </script>";
}
if($_FILES["imagen2"]["name"]){
    $editar   = mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE usuarios SET foto_portada = '$foto11' WHERE id = '".$myuser->id."' LIMIT 1");
    echo "<script> alert ('Foto de perfil actualizada correctamente.'); window.location='perfil/".$myuser->id."' </script>";
}
```

Espero me puedan ayudar no se que mas intentar

Comment: Y que problema tiene ese codigo????

Comment: Lo antes mencionado, repito: el ultimo código no funciona, quiero que suba foto de perfil y foto de portada pero no funciona, el primer codigo solo es para foto de perfil y si funciona

Comment: no funciona puede implicar que... tira un error... no tira error pero no hace lo pedido... lo hace a medias... no hace absolutamente nada... Como podemos saber, cual es el problema, si no lo estas diciendo?

Comment: Repito, nuevamente, EL SEGUNDO CODIGO NO SUBE NADA, el primer codigo es el inicial solo para subir foto de perfil antes de ser modificado, el segundo codigo es el que no hace nada, no sube imagenes, no hace nada el segundo codigo, quiero que el segundo codigo suba la imagen de perfil y la de portada pero no hace nada, si dije cual es el problema y el comentario de arriba lo volví a explicar nuevamente, lo estoy explicando por tercera vez jaja, solo necesito que suba foto de perfil y foto de portada como el primer codigo

Comment: ok..no hace nada.. el debug de todas esas variables, te da bien?? estan todas correctas??

Comment: Lo unico que hace bien es insertar en la db el nombre del archico :/ pero no sube la imagen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un problema que puedo ver es que después que se hace el primer `UPDATE` en la Base de Datos hay un `window.location= ...` que redirecciona la página antes que se haga el segundo `UPDATE`, por lo que ese registro nunca se actualiza.

Se podría hacer que el usuario actualice la foto que quisiera. Si el campo actual tiene valor no vacío, entonces se actualiza. Para facilitar el manejo se puede convertir a funciones algunos procesos.
También se agregaron las rutas como constanes `define()`. Estas deberían estar en el archivo donde tienes la configuración del sitio.

Como podrás notar, las funciones retornan valores (o `false` en caso de error). Los puedes usar para controlar qué hacer si falla algo.

```php
<?php
// ...
include_once 'assets/system/core.php';
define("UPL_PROFILE", "uploads/profile_fotos/"); // <-- esto debe estar en config
define("UPL_COVER", "uploads/cover_fotos/"); // <-- esto debe estar en config

function upload_img(string $post_id, string $dir_dst):string|bool {
    $fname  = $_FILES[$post_id]["name"];
    $fname  = rand(0,9).rand(100,9999).rand(100,9999).".".$fname;
    $src    = $_FILES[$post_id]["tmp_name"];
    $dst    = $dir_dst . $fname;
    if(!move_uploaded_file($src, $dst)) {
        return false;
    }
    return $fname;
}

function delete_img(string $full_path):bool {
    if(file_exists($full_path) and !is_dir($full_path)) {
        return unlink($full_path);
    }
    return true;
}

$selecionar = "SELECT foto_perfil, foto_portada FROM usuarios WHERE id = '$myuser->id'";
$resultado_seleccionar = mysqli_query($db, $selecionar);
$foto_db = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_seleccionar);

if(!empty($_FILES["imagen"]["name"])) {
    delete_img(UPL_PROFILE . $foto_db['foto_perfil']);
    $new_img = upload_img("imagen", UPL_PROFILE);
    mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE usuarios SET foto_perfil = '$new_img' WHERE id = '$myuser->id'");
    echo "<script> alert ('Foto de perfil actualizada correctamente.');</script>";
}
if(!empty($_FILES["imagen2"]["name"])) {
    delete_img(UPL_COVER . $foto_db['foto_portada']);
    $new_img = upload_img("imagen2", UPL_COVER);
    mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE usuarios SET foto_portada = '$new_img' WHERE id = '$myuser->id'");
    echo "<script> alert ('Foto de portada actualizada correctamente.');</script>";
}
// ...
```

Comment: muchas gracias amigo me salvaste la vida, te agradezco muchisimo

Comment: Porqué rayos el voto negativo???  @AlandRamirezAraiza si la respuesta te ha solventado considera marcarla como aceptada para que no quede en el limbo la pregunta.

Comment: @OCHOA ni idea por qué, tengo 2 respuesas seguidas con votos negativos. Y entre esas y otras curiosamente son de PHP o relacionado a web, lo cual me da posibles luces de quién es el "dedo fácil". Si bien, no me importa mucho ese puntaje, no creo que sea una buena forma de atraer, mucho menos retener, a los usuarios.

Comment: cual voto negativo OCHOA de que hablas, yo no hice ningun voto negativo, al contrario este hombre me salvo la vida, que facil es hablar verdad ochoa. Muchas gracias repito aeportugal ME SALVASTE LA VIDA

Comment: @AlandRamirezAraiza no te preocupes, sabemos que no fuiste tu. Más o menos sé quien es ese que está emitiendo *votos negativos de castigo*, pero ya eso es algo de más alto nivel en el sitio.

Comment: Ojala hagan algo por que personas como tu aeportugal que si ayudan merecen tener un buen puntaje, puro voto positivo por que lo que unico que hace es si ayudar a la comunidad, buen dia amigazo.